# Наследование абстрактного класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

У меня есть некий абстрактный класс, назовем его `Abstr`. У него есть чисто виртуальная функция, что выводит на экран принятый указатель (разыменовывает и выводит). Т.е., имеем следующее:

```
class Abstr
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    virtual void show(int *) const = 0;
    ...
};
```

От него наследуются два класса: `Test1` и `Test2`. Они переопределяют его метод show:

```
class Test1 : public Abstr
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    void show(int *) const override { ... }
    ...
};

class Test2 : public Abstr
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    void show(int *) const override { ... }
    ...
};
```

Также есть третий класс - `Test3`. Он инкапсулирует указатель на тип `int`. Тут не буду описывать все конструкторы и перегрузки операторов этого класса.

```
class Test3
{
private:
    int * ptr;
public:
    void show() const { ... }
    ...
};
```

Он тоже имеет свою функцию `show` - она выводит на экран разыменованный указатель `ptr`.
Итак, классы `Test1`, `Test2` и `Test3` похожи - они работают с указателями. Вот только первые два в методе show принимают указатель для вывода, а `Test3` выводит инкапсулированный указатель.

**Вопрос.**
Надеюсь, общую картину вы поняли. Теперь сам вопрос.
Я наследую класс `Test3` от класса `Abstr`. Но метод `show` в абстрактном классе принимает указатель, а его перегрузке в `Test3` принимать указатель не нужно, поскольку внутри класса есть поле-указатель `ptr`, что и должен выводиться в этом методе.

Т.е., я хочу наследоваться от класса `Abstr` и переопределить его чисто виртуальную функцию `show` так, чтобы она не принимала параметр. Как мне это сделать?

**Мои размышления на этот счет:**
От класса `Abstr` можно наследоваться только в классах `Test1` и `Test2`, а об идее наследования классом `Test3` забыть.
Но все же я думаю, что наследование классом `Test3` от класса `Abstr` сделало бы мой код красивее и понятнее.

Думаю, что понятно изложил вопрос. Буду очень благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: Кажется странным наследовать `Test3` от `Abstr`. Вот представьте, что вы сделали `Abstr *ptr = new Test3; ptr->show(foo);`. И что такой код должен делать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А как вы себе представляете наследование? Что компилятор должен делать, если вы напишете такой код.

```
Abstr* test = new Test3(param);
test->show(my_ptr);
```

Метод `show(int *)` должен быть у Test3 обязательно. Если это не противоречит логике класса, можно оставить оба метода, и `show(int *)` и `show()`, но, в таком случае, `show()` вы сможете вызвать только при явном приведение типа.
Если противоречит, то можно show(int*) в `Test3` заасертить или выбрасывать исключение, но это совсем не хорошая практика. Разбираться в коде, где некоторые методы объявлены но не реализованы тяжело.